# Flatten Multi Array JSON using PySpark/python

Tags: python, json, pyspark

I have a problem statement wherein I have a multi array JSON. Can you let me know a way to flatten this? Thanks in advance. Would really appreciate a quick turnaround

I tried doing this using Python but could not reach to a conclusion

Input :

```
{
  "Train1": [
    {
      "appId": "launch",
      "distributionList": [
        "abc@abc.com"
      ],
      "history": "HISTORY",
      "name": "Train1_test"
    },
    {
      "appId": "ghost",
      "distributionList": [
        "abc@abc.com"
      ],
      "history": "HISTORY",
      "name": "Train1.1_test"
    }
  ],
  "Train2": [
    {
     "appId": "alien",
      "distributionList": [
        "abc@abc.com"
      ],
      "history": "HISTORY",
      "name": "Train2_test"
    }
  ]
}
```

Expected Output:

```
    {
      "Train_flatten": [
        {
         "appId": "launch",
         "distributionList": [
          "abc@abc.com"
      ],
      "history": "HISTORY",
      "name": "Train1_test"
    },
    {
      "appId": "ghost",
      "distributionList": [
        "abc@abc.com"
      ],
      "history": "HISTORY",
      "name": "Train1.1_test"
    },
    {
     "appId": "alien",
      "distributionList": [
        "abc@abc.com"
      ],
      "history": "HISTORY",
      "name": "Train2_test"
    }
    ]

   }
```

Comment: Want to achieve the result in python or pyspark